# Is content of sticky positioned element taken out of document?

Tags: css

[MDN describes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) `position: sticky;` as

> Sticky positioning can be thought of as a hybrid of relative and fixed
>   positioning. A stickily positioned element is treated as relatively
>   positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it
>   is treated as fixed until it reaches the boundary of its parent. For
>   instance...
>
> ```
> #one { position: sticky; top: 10px; }
> ```
>
> ...would position the element with id one relatively until the
>   viewport were scrolled such that the element would be less than 10
>   pixels from the top. Beyond that threshold, the element would be fixed
>   to 10 pixels from the top.

**Question:** If the threshold of those `10px` is reached, is the element `is taken out of the flow of the document`, thus making content leap a bit to the top?

Comment: Doesn't the example on the page (your link) answer your question?

Comment: @Huangism yes, but this may be browser specific.

Comment: Scroll down, there is a section on browser compatibility. You can also load the page on different browsers

Answer (score 0):

It does not, nor sohuld it - that would defeat the purpose of sticky positionioning. If it happens in some browser (it doesn't in any I'm aware of), then it's a bug and should (and will) get fixed asap if you report it, as it's probably breaking a bunch of web applications using it.